# Tag 'CreateStudent' expects at least '5' arguments, but the JSX factory 'React.createElement' provides at most '2'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a function to get a student's name, age, and e-mail input and register in the array.

index.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Student from "./UserList";
import CreateStudent from "./CreateUser";

function StudentList() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState<any>([
    {
      id: "st001",
      name: "김남준",
      age: 28,
      email: "rm@gmail.com",
    },
  ]);

  const nextId = useRef(2);

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    name: "",
    age: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const { name, age, email } = inputs;

  const onDataChange = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any } }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setInputs({
      ...inputs,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const onCreate = () => {
    const student = {
      id: "st00" + nextId.current,
      name,
      age,
      email,
    };
    setStudents([...students, student]);

    setInputs({
      name: "",
      age: "",
      email: "",
    });
    nextId.current += 1;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CreateStudent
        name={name}
        age={age}
        email={email}
        onDataChange={onDataChange}
        onCreate={onCreate}
      />
      {students.map((student: { id: React.Key | null | undefined }) => (
        <Student student={student} key={student.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default StudentList;
```

./CreateStudent.tsx

```
import React from "react";

function CreateStudent(
  { name }: { name: any },
  { age }: { age: any },
  { email }: { email: any },
  { onDataChange }: { onDataChange: any },
  { onCreate }: { onCreate: any }
) {

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name" onChange={onDataChange} value={name} />
      <input type="text" name="age" onChange={onDataChange} value={age} />
      <input type="text" name="email" onChange={onDataChange} value={email} />
      <button onClick={onCreate}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateStudent;
```

This is the content of the error that occurred to me.

Tag 'CreateStudent' expects at least '5' arguments, but the JSX factory 'React.createElement' provides at most '2'.

1. name={name}
2. age={age}
3. email={email}
4. onDataChange={onDataChange}
5. onCreate={onCreate}

I'm actually using these five arguments.

Why are errors occurring here and how do I resolve them?

Answer (score 2):

The `CreateStudent` is a react functional component, and in most cases it should just accept only one `props` argument. In your case, you should destructure the `props` into **5 keys** instead of **5 arguments**.

```
interface CreateStudentProps {
  name: any;
  age: any;
  email: any;
  onDataChange: any;
  onCreate: any;
}

function CreateStudent({
  name,
  age,
  email,
  onDataChange,
  onCreate
}: CreateStudentProps) {
  ...your code here
}
```